# Tor unable to read /etc/tor/torrc and isn't saving log on /var/log/tor

Tags: configuration, log

I just installed Tor on my server and am still using default torrc. It's Ubuntu 20.04.

systemctl reports it's active, but ps doesn't list it. /var/log/tor is empty, its permissions is

`drwxr-s---  2 debian-tor adm    4096 dez 31 16:18 ./`

/etc/tor is

```
ll /etc/tor
total 32
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 dez 31 16:34 ./
drwxr-xr-x 147 root root 12288 dez 31 16:34 ../
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  8888 dez 31 16:34 torrc
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  2087 dez 31 16:34 torsocks.conf
```

Verifying /var/log/syslog it seems it's unable to read /etc/tor/torrc:

```
Dec 31 16:21:32 Urubu4 tor[27542]: Dec 31 16:21:32.533 [notice] Tor 0.4.4.6 running on Linux with Libevent 2.1.11-stable, OpenSSL 1.1.1f, Zlib 1.2.11, Liblzma 5.2.4, and Libzstd 1.4.4.
Dec 31 16:21:32 Urubu4 tor[27542]: Dec 31 16:21:32.533 [notice] Tor can't help you if you use it wrong! Learn how to be safe at https://www.torproject.org/download/download#warning
Dec 31 16:21:32 Urubu4 tor[27542]: Dec 31 16:21:32.533 [notice] Read configuration file "/usr/share/tor/tor-service-defaults-torrc".
Dec 31 16:21:32 Urubu4 tor[27542]: Dec 31 16:21:32.533 [notice] Read configuration file "/etc/tor/torrc".
Dec 31 16:21:32 Urubu4 tor[27542]: Dec 31 16:21:32.534 [notice] Based on detected system memory, MaxMemInQueues is set to 8192 MB. You can override this by setting MaxMemInQueues by hand.
Dec 31 16:21:32 Urubu4 tor[27542]: Dec 31 16:21:32.534 [warn] Can't set a DirPort on a bridge relay; disabling DirPort
Dec 31 16:21:32 Urubu4 tor[27542]: Configuration was valid
Dec 31 16:21:32 Urubu4 tor[27546]: Dec 31 16:21:32.548 [notice] Tor 0.4.4.6 running on Linux with Libevent 2.1.11-stable, OpenSSL 1.1.1f, Zlib 1.2.11, Liblzma 5.2.4, and Libzstd 1.4.4.
Dec 31 16:21:32 Urubu4 tor[27546]: Dec 31 16:21:32.548 [notice] Tor can't help you if you use it wrong! Learn how to be safe at https://www.torproject.org/download/download#warning
Dec 31 16:21:32 Urubu4 tor[27546]: Dec 31 16:21:32.548 [notice] Read configuration file "/usr/share/tor/tor-service-defaults-torrc".
Dec 31 16:21:32 Urubu4 tor[27546]: Dec 31 16:21:32.548 [warn] Could not open "/etc/tor/torrc": Permission denied
Dec 31 16:21:32 Urubu4 tor[27546]: Dec 31 16:21:32.548 [warn] Unable to open configuration file "/etc/tor/torrc".
Dec 31 16:21:32 Urubu4 tor[27546]: Dec 31 16:21:32.548 [err] Reading config failed--see warnings above.
Dec 31 16:21:32 Urubu4 systemd[1]: tor@default.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Dec 31 16:21:32 Urubu4 systemd[1]: tor@default.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Dec 31 16:21:32 Urubu4 systemd[1]: Failed to start Anonymizing overlay network for TCP.
```

What might be wrong?

Comment: You can check the status with `systemctl status tor@default` and the log with `journalctl -u tor@default`. Are you sure the torrc has the default settings? The line `Can't set a DirPort on a bridge relay; disabling DirPort` suggests that something has been changed.

Comment: tnx! I'm setting up a new Ubuntu server and using Macrium to make backups of its partition. I had installed Tor before and had issues, so I restored the backup from before I had installed it and did it again with default settings. I can assure I had just installed it following https://support.torproject.org/apt/tor-deb-repo/ and https://community.torproject.org/relay/setup/bridge/debian-ubuntu/ and had made no changes on /etc/tor, specially on its permissions (because of this odd permissions denied error). I verified once more and whole torrc is fully commented.

Comment: What's the difference of service tor@default.service and tor.service?

Comment: This is odd... tor@default.service was running, IDK if that's why tor.service was failing. I tried stopping and starting both and they generate different logs on journalctl, none of them on /var/log/tor. tor@default is more detailed.

Comment: Somehow I got confused on tor.service and tor@default.service. /var/log/tor is empty but `journalctl -u tor@default` shows the proper log, I applied my custom torrc and it's working.

Comment: The tor deb allows you to run multiple tor instances under the one tor service, so `tor@default` is the default tor instance for the tor service. For more details, see [`tor-instance-create`](https://manpages.debian.org/testing/tor/tor-instance-create.8.en.html). Tor by default doesn't write to `/var/log/tor`, so you should only see the log using `journalctl`. But glad you got it working now!

Comment: If u can add it as answer I'll mark it as solution.

Comment: Indeed, now with my torrc I got log on /var/log/tor! I just looked on its first startup, it's touching to watch a new relay being born and working healthly :D